# CreateProcess with cmd.exe hanging when program has lots of output

Tags: c, windows, winapi, cmd, process

I'm using `CreateProcess` to call `cmd.exe` with a custom command:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  HANDLE stdout_w = NULL;
  HANDLE stdout_r = NULL;

  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sattr = { 0 };
  sattr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
  sattr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

  if (!CreatePipe(&stdout_r, &stdout_w, &sattr, 0))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  SetHandleInformation(stdout_r, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
  STARTUPINFOA si = { 0 };

  si.cb = sizeof(si);
  si.hStdError = stdout_w;
  si.hStdOutput = stdout_w;
  si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

  char command[256];
  strcpy_s(command, _countof(command), "cmd /S /C \"ag \"ch\"\"");

  if (!CreateProcessA(NULL, command, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, "c:/users/lisa/projects/monkey", &si, &pi))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

  while (true) {
    switch (WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 0)) {
      case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        break;
      case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
      default:
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }
}
```

Here, I'm calling `cmd.exe` with the command `ag "ch"`. (`ag` is a utility that searches files for a string, kind of like `grep`.)

The problem is, it's hanging---the loop at the end runs forever, and I can see the created `cmd.exe` process staying open in Task Manager. A couple weird things about this:

- When I run `cmd.exe /S /C "ag "ch""` directly from Command Prompt, it works fine and exits as expected.
- When I change the code to run `ag "chi"` (i.e. searching for a larger substring), it exits as expected. Also, when I change the directory to a folder without any files, it also exits as expected. This makes me think the problem is when the output of `ag` is too long.
- When I directly pass the `ag "ch"` command to `CreateProcess`, it exits as expected. (Unfortunately, I can't do this because this is part of a larger utility that lets me run any batch command from C, including using pipes.)

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: I would expect your command text string to be `"cmd /S /C ag \"ch\""` and not `"cmd /S /C \"ag \"ch\"\""`. Looks to me like too many double quotes resulting in a command line of `cmd /S /C "ag "ch""` and what you want is `cmd /S /c ag "ch"`.

Comment: why you run cmd instead direct *ag.exe* ? where you use redirected output ? for what you redirect it ? you nothing read or write to pipes

Comment: This code is stripped out of a larger utility class that lets me call any batch command (e.g. `ag ch | filter`) and read the output. This code is just to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @RichardChambers I think the extra quotes are right (see the section on `/S` under `cmd /?`), but either way, I removed the extra quotes and I'm getting the same issue. Also, if I simply change the command slightly from `ch` to `child`, it works as expected.

Comment: The pipe is full so the program can't write any more data to it. You have to read the already-written data from the pipe to make room for more.

Comment: @RaymondChen That was it, thanks!

Comment: CMD will always strip the first and last quote characters with `/S`, which is fine so long as the whole `/C` command line is wrapped in an extra set of quotes.

Comment: Why are you calling `WaitForSingleObject()` in a tight loop with a 0ms timeout? Get rid of such a polling loop altogether and just call `WaitForSingleObject()` one time with an `INFINITE` timeout instead.

Comment: Not related to the issue but in Windows a backslash is used rather than a forward slash in paths (although Windows is forgiving).